# git word-diff-regex for CSV files

Tags: regex, git, git-diff

I'm trying to compare two CSV files where I know the changes will be in a single column.

If I compare like this, the results show red and green text for unchanged sections of text before and after the column that is actually changed:

```
git diff --no-index --word-diff=color file1.csv file2.csv
```

I'm experimenting with word-diff-regex to define a "word" as any text followed by a comma.  So far I have not found the correct expression.

```
# This doesn't work properly    
git diff --no-index --word-diff=color --word-diff-regex=".*," file1.csv file2.csv
```

What is the right word-diff-regex expression to show changes to a single CSV column?

Comment: IMO you are using wrong tool for this job. I have commercial tool Beyond Compare which has ability to see differences in CSV files. Maybe try [this online tool](https://extendsclass.com/csv-diff.html#result).

Answer (score 1):

`-word-diff-regex` wants to be given the things that are your words, and ignore the things that don't match. Also don't need the quotes you have. A regex of just `.`  can work - it will treat every character as a separate change.

`git diff --no-index --word-diff=color --word-diff-regex=. file1.csv file2.csv`

Or a regex of `[^,]+` can work for CSV, it will treat everything that is not a comma as a change, and the + makes it group them into a word.... but can sometimes do weird things if a field is added or removed, so my most recent method has been a regex of `,[^,]+` so it captures an added field along with its comma, only doesn't work if the first field is changed.

`git diff --no-index --word-diff=color --word-diff-regex=,[^,]+ file1.csv file2.csv`